# How to create blank dataframe in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Dataframe is unreachable outside the if clause. how to access Dataframe outside if/else block

**Requirement**: DataSource id SQL Server and from structured data prepare JSON
Scenario: Based on region value will populate data and will fit it within main dataframe. Problem occurred when I am trying to access dataframe outside the if/else clause.
Below is the code sample that I have tried:

```
if(region == "UK") {
  val dfUK = "select * from tablename"
}
dfuk.withColumnRenamed("ColumnName1","ColumnName2")


    
**Error: dfuk is unreachable**
```

Answer (score 0):

**Resolution:**

1. Import the library - import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
2. Create blank dataframe:

```scala
    var outputdf: DataFrame = _
    if(region == "UK")
    {
        val dfUK = "select * from tablename"
        outputdf = dfUK 
    }
    outputdf.withColumnRenamed("ColumnName1","ColumnName2")
```

Comment: Try this :   spark.emptyDataFrame

Answer (score 0):

define it as an expression

```
val dfUK = if(region == "UK") { 
   spark.sql("select * from tablename")
} //else something other definition for the df    
dfUK.withColumn...
```